# Python - how to find where string A occurs in string B, but allowing for a certain number of errors

Tags: python

The goal of this program is to find the starting position in B where A is found as a substring with the least number of errors.  The maximum number of errors allowed is mxe.
The function should return a pair of numbers, (ai,ae) where ai is the
position B where the match was found, and ae is the number of errors in the
match.

```
def sameletter(a,b):
    if a==b:return True

 
def bestmatch(A,B,mxe):
    bx = -1
    errorsatbx = mxe + 1
    k = 0
    while k<len(B)-len(A) and bx == -1:
        ax = 0
        i = 0
        while i<len(A) and ax <= mxe:
            if not(sameletter(A[i],B[i+k])):               
          
      i+=1
        if ax <= mxe: bx = k
        k += 1

    return(bx, mxe)

bestmatch("ACTG","GTCACTGATC", 1)
```

The program runs but nothing is returned.

Comment: Find the index at which the [levenshtein distance](https://pypi.org/project/Levenshtein/) is minimized?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). You can indent code blocks _or_ fence them; you don't need to do both. And note that code fences use _backticks_ (`\``), not quotes.

Comment: The `i+=1` is unreachable because of the `continue`. So you have an infinite loop.

Comment: The "if" in the inner "while" looks suspicious (unless it's a formatting error):   the "i+=1" is an unreachable statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try this:

```py
def sameletter(a,b):
    if a == b:
        return True

def bestmatch(A,B,mxe):
    bx = -1
    errorsatbx = mxe + 1
    k = 0
    while k < int(len(B) - len(A)) and bx == -1:
        ax = 0
        i = 0
        while i < len(A) and ax <= mxe:
            if not(sameletter(A[i],B[i+k])):
                i += 1
        if ax <= mxe:
            bx = k
        k += 1

    return(bx, mxe)

print (bestmatch("ACTG","GTCACTGATC", 1))
```

It at least returns values, but I don't know if the values are what you want or correct